# Inserir linha JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um exemplo de validação para uma table dinâmica e gostaria de uma ajuda em bug aqui. Quando faço a primeira inserção ele dá certinho, quando mudo, ele deixar inserir e duplica.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  // alert('teste');
  var cont = 0;
  var count = $('#mytbody').children('tr').length;
  var vIdEmpresa = $('#selectEmpresa option:selected').val();
  var vEmpresa = $('#selectEmpresa option:selected').text();

  if (!count) {
    // console.log('vazio');
    var linha = '<tr class="selected" id="linha' + cont + '">' +
      '<td>' +
      '<input class="idemp" type="hidden" name="idempresa[]" value="' + vIdEmpresa + '">' + vEmpresa +
      '</td>' +
      ' </tr>'
    cont++;
    $('#mytbody').append(linha);
  } else {
    $(".idemp").each(function(index, value) {
      var vText = console.log($(this).text());

      if ($(value).val() == vIdEmpresa) {
        console.log('Empresa ja foi adicionada!');
      } else {
        var linha = '<tr class="selected" id="linha' + cont + '">' +
          '<td>' +
          '<input class="idemp" type="hidden" name="idempresa[]" value="' + vIdEmpresa + '">' + vEmpresa +
          '</td>' +
          ' </tr>'
        cont++;
        $('#mytbody').append(linha);
      }
    })
  }


});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="selectEmpresa">
        <option value="1">Empresa 01</option>
        <option value="2">Empresa 02</option>
        <option value="3">Empresa 03</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" name="button">Adicionar</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Empresa</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="mytbody">

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Exemplo**

```js
  $("button").click(function() {
  $('#selectEmpresa').change(function(){
    $('#msg').html('');
  });

  var vIdEmpresa = $('#selectEmpresa option:selected').val();
  var vEmpresa = $('#selectEmpresa option:selected').text();
  var mensagem = $('#msg');
  var linha = '<tr class="selected" id="linha' + vIdEmpresa + '">' +
        '<td>' +
        '<input class="idemp" type="hidden" name="idempresa' + vIdEmpresa + '" value="' + vIdEmpresa + '">' + vEmpresa +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        `<select class="form-control" id="autoriza">
          <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
          <option value="Não">Não</option>
        </select>`+
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        `<input type="checkbox"  value="Sim">`+
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        `<input type="radio" name="teste"  value="Sim"> Sim
         <input type="radio" name="teste" value="Nao"> Não`+
        '</td>' +
        ' </tr>'

  if($("tr#linha" + vIdEmpresa).length === 0) {
    $('#mytbody').append(linha);
  } else {
    $('#msg').html("<b class='text-danger'>&#9888; Empresa " + vIdEmpresa + " já foi adicionada!</b>");
  }
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="selectEmpresa">
        <option value="01">Empresa 01</option>
        <option value="02">Empresa 02</option>
        <option value="03">Empresa 03</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" name="button">Adicionar</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <span id="msg"></span><br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Empresa</th>
            <th>Autoriza</th>
            <th>Checa</th>
            <th>Opção</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="mytbody">

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Utilize o console do desenvolvedor do seu navegador e observe o log de erro que ele mostra, para ajudar a identificar o problema.

Comment: obrigado pelo retorno. Estou utilizando ele nao retorno erro, apenas duplica tudo.

Comment: Sua dúvida não ficou muito clara.

Comment: Vou tentar detalhar melhor. Ao adicionar do select pra a table ele não pode deixar inserir em duplicidade, precisa barrar e informar ao usuário que já foi inserido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é o laço que você faz:

```
$(".idemp").each(function(index, value) {
```

Esse laço é usado para verificar se a empresa já foi adicionada percorrendo todos os itens da tabela. O problema é que o `append` da empresa está sendo feito antes de comparar e empresa adicionada a todas as empresas da tabela. Você precisa modificar teu código para fazer o `append` fora do laço de verificação, algo como:

```
var empresaJaAdicionada = false;
$(".idemp").each(function(index, value) {
  var vText = console.log($(this).text());
  if ($(value).val() == vIdEmpresa) {
    console.log('Empresa ja foi adicionada!');
    empresaJaAdicionada = true;
  }
});
if (!empresaJaAdicionada) {
    var linha = '<tr class="selected" id="linha' + cont + '">' +
      '<td>' +
      '<input class="idemp" type="hidden" name="idempresa[]" value="' + vIdEmpresa + '">' + vEmpresa +
      '</td>' +
      ' </tr>'
    cont++;
    $('#mytbody').append(linha);
}
```

Veja que foi criada a variável `empresaJaAdicionada` para armazenar se a empresa foi encontrada na tabela ou não. O ponto chave aqui é que o código de adição da empresa na tabela será agora executado após o forEach, garantindo assim que todas as empresas foram consultadas e a nova empresa não foi encontrada, podendo então ser adicionada.

A versão final ficaria da seguinte forma:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  // alert('teste');
  var cont = 0;
  var count = $('#mytbody').children('tr').length;
  var vIdEmpresa = $('#selectEmpresa option:selected').val();
  var vEmpresa = $('#selectEmpresa option:selected').text();

  if (!count) {
    // console.log('vazio');
    var linha = '<tr class="selected" id="linha' + cont + '">' +
      '<td>' +
      '<input class="idemp" type="hidden" name="idempresa[]" value="' + vIdEmpresa + '">' + vEmpresa +
      '</td>' +
      ' </tr>'
    cont++;
    $('#mytbody').append(linha);
  } else {
    var empresaJaAdicionada = false;
    $(".idemp").each(function(index, value) {
      var vText = console.log($(this).text());
      if ($(value).val() == vIdEmpresa) {
        console.log('Empresa ja foi adicionada!');
        empresaJaAdicionada = true;
      }
    });
    if (!empresaJaAdicionada) {
     var linha = '<tr class="selected" id="linha' + cont + '">' +
    '<td>' +
    '<input class="idemp" type="hidden" name="idempresa[]" value="' + vIdEmpresa + '">' + vEmpresa +
    '</td>' +
    ' </tr>'
     cont++;
     $('#mytbody').append(linha);
    }
  }


});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="selectEmpresa">
        <option value="1">Empresa 01</option>
        <option value="2">Empresa 02</option>
        <option value="3">Empresa 03</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" name="button">Adicionar</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Empresa</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="mytbody">

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

OBS: Existe uma forma mais elegante de fazer essa verificação. Uma delas é criar um vetor de empresas e manipulá-lo durante a adição de empresas, ao invés de verificar no DOM se o elemento está presente.

Comment: Obrigado Giuliana, percebo que vacilei ai mesmo, faz sentido. Ref. ao vetor vou pesquisar sobre isso se tiver alguma sujestão de pesquisa poste por favor, gostaria de montar esses exemplos e postar para quem tiver duvida. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Eu gosto muito desse curso de javascript: https://watchandcode.com/courses/60264/lectures/896960. Ele ensina a criar uma TODO List com essa estratégia de manipular os dados da mesma separadamente da view, o que se aplicaria ao teu exemplo. Se tiver tempo, eu recomendo.

Comment: Ok. Vou acessar.Mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: É preciso fazer dois pequenos ajustes no script da @GiulianaBezerra. 1-) Todas as TR estão com o mesmo ID: `linha0`. **Correção**: Defina `vIdEmpresa` para a numeração do ID em lugar de `count` como está no script. 2-) Todos os `input` estão com o mesmo valor de atributo `name`. **Correção**: Mesmo critério descrito acima.

Comment: Obrigado. Maujor. muito bom mesmo. Vou compartilhar.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui está uma solução "mais elegante" como sugerida pela @Giuliana Bezerra.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
$('#selectEmpresa').change(function(){
  $('#msg').html('');
});

var vIdEmpresa = $('#selectEmpresa option:selected').val();
var vEmpresa = $('#selectEmpresa option:selected').text();
var mensagem = $('#msg');
var linha = '<tr class="selected" id="linha' + vIdEmpresa + '">' +
      '<td>' +
      '<input class="idemp" type="hidden" name="idempresa' + vIdEmpresa + '" value="' + vIdEmpresa + '">' + vEmpresa +
      '</td>' +
      ' </tr>'  
 
if($("tr#linha" + vIdEmpresa).length === 0) {
  $('#mytbody').append(linha); 
} else {
  $('#msg').html("<b class='text-danger'>&#9888; Empresa " + vIdEmpresa + " já foi adicionada!</b>"); 
} 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="selectEmpresa">
        <option value="01">Empresa 01</option>
        <option value="02">Empresa 02</option>
        <option value="03">Empresa 03</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" name="button">Adicionar</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <span id="msg"></span><br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Empresa</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="mytbody">

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show de bola, aprendi um pouco mais.

Comment: Agora so pra exemplificar Maujor e se acrescentascemos uma coluna com select e outra com checkbox e outra com radio como seria?

Comment: @frodrigues Poderia detalhar melhor o que você pretende?

Comment: Sim claro. Pretendo acrescentar no exemplo acima alem de input, uma coluna com select, uma radio e uma com checkox em cada linha dinâmica e fazer a verificação de cada um deles assim como fizemos com o input. Vou postar um exemplo.

Comment: Agora tem um detalhe e para pegar o request isso e salvar no banco? Testei aqui e deu : count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: @frodrigues Aguardo detalhes. Não entendi o que você pretende fazer.

Comment: Gostaria apenas se possivel complementar o exemplo. Fazendo a checagem do que esta marcado no checkbox, no radio e no select. Só para exemplo mesmo.